# outer join solution for a query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

How do I retrieve these rows in the best optimum time ?

One table is called TJOBSTATUS and it has a JOB_ID and JOB_STATUS.
The other table is called TJOB_DETAIL and it has JOB_ID as a foreign key and JOB_TYPEID and other columns.

I want to retrieve all rows that dont contain a JOB_TYPEID, but are in a failed status in the table TJOBSTATUS.

Example :- 
Rows of TJOBSTATUS =

```
JOB_ID   JOB_STATUS
1        F
2        P
3        F
4        P
5        P
```

Rows of TJOB_DETAIL :-

```
JOB_ID       JOB_TYPEID
1                28
1                12
1                14
2                12
2                14
3                13
3                15
4                28
5                25
5                26
```

Here I want to show JOB_ID 3 , as it failed and it DOES NOT contain JOB_TYPEID 28

I have written a very slow query something like :-

```
SELECT TJ.JOB_ID 
FROM TJOBSTATUS TJ 
WHERE TJ.JOB_STATUS='F' 
  AND TJ.JOB_ID NOT IN (SELECT TJD.JOB_ID 
                        FROM TJOB_DETAIL TJD 
                        WHERE (TJD.JOB_TYPEID=28) 
  AND TJD.JOBDATE > SYSDATE - 7);
```

Please let me know if we can write a better query, using outer joins or similar techniques.

Comment: You may try with `NOT EXISTS`  instead of join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance questions are hard to answer without additional informations (execution plan, indices, etc). Anyway you could try `not exists` version.

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/KVG86873)</sup>**

```
select job_id 
  from tjobstatus tj 
  where job_status = 'F' 
    and not exists (
      select 1 from tjob_detail 
       where job_id = tj.job_id and job_typeid = 28 );
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I am going to check and see if that improves performance for this report.